# Problems with rendering texture in Qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml, directx, render

I need to render a 2D texture using DirectX 11 in a Qml window.
I used this example - https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquick-scenegraph-d3d11underqml-example.html.

I already have a program that displays a 2D texture in a Qml window using OpenGL.

But there are problems with DirectX - textures are displayed in the window only for one frame, and then the standard window fill is shown

Here is my code

```
//d3d11squircle.h
#ifndef D3D11SQUIRCLE_H
#define D3D11SQUIRCLE_H

#include <QtQuick/QQuickItem>

class SquircleRenderer;

class D3D11Squircle : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal t READ t WRITE setT NOTIFY tChanged)
    QML_ELEMENT

public:
    D3D11Squircle();

    qreal t() const { return m_t; }
    void setT(qreal t);
    bool tmp = false;
signals:
    void tChanged();

public slots:
    void sync();
    void cleanup();

private slots:
    void handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win);

private:
    void releaseResources() override;

    qreal m_t;
    SquircleRenderer *m_renderer = nullptr;
};

#endif
```

```
//d3d11squircle.cpp

#include "d3d11squircle.h"
#include <QtCore/QFile>
#include <QtCore/QRunnable>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickWindow>

#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include "stb_image.h"

float VertexData[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
};

class SquircleRenderer : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    SquircleRenderer();
    ~SquircleRenderer();

    void render();
    void setT(qreal t) { m_t = t; }
    void setViewportSize(const QSize &size) { m_viewportSize = size; }
    void setWindow(QQuickWindow *window) { m_window = window; }
    bool m_initialized = false;
public slots:
    void frameStart();
    void mainPassRecordingStart();

private:
    enum Stage {
        VertexStage,
        FragmentStage
    };
    void prepareShader(Stage stage);
    QByteArray compileShader(Stage stage,
                             const QByteArray &source,
                             const QByteArray &entryPoint);
    void init();

    QSize m_viewportSize;
    qreal m_t;
    QQuickWindow *m_window;

    ID3D11Device *m_device = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *m_context = nullptr;
    QByteArray m_vert;
    QByteArray m_vertEntryPoint;
    QByteArray m_frag;
    QByteArray m_fragEntryPoint;


    ID3D11Buffer *m_vbuf = nullptr;
    ID3D11Buffer *m_cbuf = nullptr;
    ID3D11VertexShader *m_vs = nullptr;
    ID3D11PixelShader *m_ps = nullptr;
    ID3D11InputLayout *m_inputLayout = nullptr;
    ID3D11RasterizerState *m_rastState = nullptr;
    ID3D11DepthStencilState *m_dsState = nullptr;
    ID3D11BlendState *m_blendState = nullptr;
    ID3D11Texture2D* m_texture = nullptr;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView * m_renderTarget = nullptr;
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* m_shaderResourceView = nullptr;
    ID3D11SamplerState* m_imageSamplerState = nullptr;
    ID3D11Buffer* m_vertexData = nullptr;
    IDXGISwapChain1 *m_swapChain = nullptr;
};

D3D11Squircle::D3D11Squircle()
    : m_t(0)
    , m_renderer(nullptr)
{
    connect(this, &QQuickItem::windowChanged, this, &D3D11Squircle::handleWindowChanged);
}

void D3D11Squircle::setT(qreal t)
{
    if (t == m_t)
        return;
    m_t = t;
    emit tChanged();
    if (window())
        window()->update();
}

void D3D11Squircle::handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow *win)
{
    if (win) {
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::beforeSynchronizing, this, &D3D11Squircle::sync, Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(win, &QQuickWindow::sceneGraphInvalidated, this, &D3D11Squircle::cleanup, Qt::DirectConnection);

        // Ensure we start with cleared to black. The squircle's blend mode relies on this.
        win->setColor(Qt::lightGray);
//        qDebug("PAINT\n");
//        if (tmp) {
//            m_renderer->render();
//        }
    }
}

SquircleRenderer::SquircleRenderer()
    : m_t(0)
{
}

void D3D11Squircle::cleanup()
{
    delete m_renderer;
    m_renderer = nullptr;
}

class CleanupJob : public QRunnable
{
public:
    CleanupJob(SquircleRenderer *renderer) : m_renderer(renderer) { }
    void run() override { delete m_renderer; }
private:
    SquircleRenderer *m_renderer;
};

void D3D11Squircle::releaseResources()
{
    window()->scheduleRenderJob(new CleanupJob(m_renderer), QQuickWindow::BeforeSynchronizingStage);
    m_renderer = nullptr;
}

SquircleRenderer::~SquircleRenderer()
{
    qDebug("cleanup");

    if (m_vs)
        m_vs->Release();

    if (m_ps)
        m_ps->Release();

    if (m_vbuf)
        m_vbuf->Release();

    if (m_cbuf)
        m_cbuf->Release();

    if (m_inputLayout)
        m_inputLayout->Release();

    if (m_rastState)
        m_rastState->Release();

    if (m_dsState)
        m_dsState->Release();

    if (m_blendState)
        m_blendState->Release();
}

void D3D11Squircle::sync()
{
    if (!m_renderer) {
        m_renderer = new SquircleRenderer;
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, m_renderer, &SquircleRenderer::frameStart, Qt::DirectConnection);
        connect(window(), &QQuickWindow::beforeRenderPassRecording, m_renderer, &SquircleRenderer::mainPassRecordingStart, Qt::DirectConnection);
        tmp = true;
    }
    m_renderer->setViewportSize(window()->size() * window()->devicePixelRatio());
    m_renderer->setT(m_t);
    m_renderer->setWindow(window());
}

void SquircleRenderer::frameStart()
{
    QSGRendererInterface *rif = m_window->rendererInterface();

    // We are not prepared for anything other than running with the RHI and its D3D11 backend.
    Q_ASSERT(rif->graphicsApi() == QSGRendererInterface::Direct3D11Rhi);

    m_device = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11Device *>(rif->getResource(m_window, QSGRendererInterface::DeviceResource));
    Q_ASSERT(m_device);
    m_context = reinterpret_cast<ID3D11DeviceContext *>(rif->getResource(m_window, QSGRendererInterface::DeviceContextResource));
    Q_ASSERT(m_context);

    if (m_vert.isEmpty())
        prepareShader(VertexStage);
    if (m_frag.isEmpty())
        prepareShader(FragmentStage);

    if (!m_initialized)
        init();
}
#include <ctime>
void SquircleRenderer::mainPassRecordingStart()
{
    //while (1) {
    //time_t Time= time(NULL);
    m_window->beginExternalCommands();

    //while(1) {
        render();
        //if (time(NULL) - Time == 10) {
            //break;
        //}
    //}

    m_window->endExternalCommands();
    //}
}

void SquircleRenderer::prepareShader(Stage stage)
{
    QString filename;
    if (stage == VertexStage) {
        filename = QLatin1String(":/scenegraph/d3d11underqml/shaders.hlsl");
    } else {
        Q_ASSERT(stage == FragmentStage);
        filename = QLatin1String(":/scenegraph/d3d11underqml/shaders.hlsl");
    }
    QFile f(filename);
    if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        qFatal("Failed to read shader %s", qPrintable(filename));

    const QByteArray contents = f.readAll();

    if (stage == VertexStage) {
        m_vert = contents;
        Q_ASSERT(!m_vert.isEmpty());
        m_vertEntryPoint = QByteArrayLiteral("vs_main");
    } else {
        m_frag = contents;
        Q_ASSERT(!m_frag.isEmpty());
        m_fragEntryPoint = QByteArrayLiteral("ps_main");
    }
}

QByteArray SquircleRenderer::compileShader(Stage stage, const QByteArray &source, const QByteArray &entryPoint)
{
    const char *target;
    switch (stage) {
    case VertexStage:
        target = "vs_5_0";
        break;
    case FragmentStage:
        target = "ps_5_0";
        break;
    default:
        qFatal("Unknown shader stage %d", stage);
        return QByteArray();
    }

    ID3DBlob *bytecode = nullptr;
    ID3DBlob *errors = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = D3DCompile(source.constData(), source.size(),
                            nullptr, nullptr, nullptr,
                            entryPoint.constData(), target, 0, 0, &bytecode, &errors);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !bytecode) {
        qWarning("HLSL shader compilation failed: 0x%x", uint(hr));
        if (errors) {
            const QByteArray msg(static_cast<const char *>(errors->GetBufferPointer()),
                                 errors->GetBufferSize());
            errors->Release();
            qWarning("%s", msg.constData());
        }
        return QByteArray();
    }

    QByteArray result;
    result.resize(bytecode->GetBufferSize());
    memcpy(result.data(), bytecode->GetBufferPointer(), result.size());
    bytecode->Release();

    return result;
}

void SquircleRenderer::init()
{
    qDebug("init");
    m_initialized = true;

    const QByteArray vs = compileShader(VertexStage, m_vert, m_vertEntryPoint);
    const QByteArray fs = compileShader(FragmentStage, m_frag, m_fragEntryPoint);

    HRESULT hr = m_device->CreateVertexShader(vs.constData(), vs.size(), nullptr, &m_vs);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        qFatal("Failed to create vertex shader: 0x%x", hr);

    hr = m_device->CreatePixelShader(fs.constData(), fs.size(), nullptr, &m_ps);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        qFatal("Failed to create pixel shader: 0x%x", hr);

    // init vertex buffer
    {
        D3D11_BUFFER_DESC VertexDataDesc = {
            sizeof(VertexData),
            D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT,
            D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER,
            0, 0, 0
        };

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA VertexDataInitial = { VertexData };
        hr = m_device->CreateBuffer(&VertexDataDesc, &VertexDataInitial, &m_vertexData);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    }

    // init input layout
    {
        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputDesc;
        memset(&inputDesc, 0, sizeof(inputDesc));
        inputDesc.SemanticName = "POSITION";
        inputDesc.SemanticIndex = 0;
        inputDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT; // vec2
        inputDesc.InputSlot = 0;
        inputDesc.AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
        inputDesc.InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;

        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputDesc2;
        memset(&inputDesc2, 0, sizeof(inputDesc2));
        inputDesc2.SemanticName = "UV";
        inputDesc2.SemanticIndex = 0;
        inputDesc2.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT; // vec2
        inputDesc2.InputSlot = 0;
        inputDesc2.AlignedByteOffset = D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT;
        inputDesc2.InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;

        D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputs[] = { inputDesc, inputDesc2 };

        int iNumElements = sizeof(inputs) / sizeof(D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC);

        hr = m_device->CreateInputLayout(inputs, iNumElements, vs.constData(), vs.size(), &m_inputLayout);
        if (FAILED(hr))
            qFatal("Failed to create input layout: 0x%x", hr);
    }

    // init swap chain
    {
        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 SwapChainDesc = {};
        SwapChainDesc.Width = 0;
        SwapChainDesc.Height = 0;
        SwapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
        SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        SwapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        SwapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
        SwapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
        SwapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
        SwapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
        SwapChainDesc.AlphaMode = DXGI_ALPHA_MODE_UNSPECIFIED;
        SwapChainDesc.Flags = 0;

        IDXGIDevice2 *DxgiDevice;
        hr = m_device->QueryInterface(__uuidof(IDXGIDevice2), (void **)&DxgiDevice);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        IDXGIAdapter *DxgiAdapter;
        hr = DxgiDevice->GetAdapter(&DxgiAdapter);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        DxgiDevice->Release();

        IDXGIFactory2 *DxgiFactory;
        hr = DxgiAdapter->GetParent(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory2), (void **)&DxgiFactory);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        DxgiAdapter->Release();

        hr = DxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(m_device, (HWND)m_window->winId(), &SwapChainDesc, 0, 0, &m_swapChain);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        DxgiFactory->Release();
    }

    // init texture
    {
        int ImageWidth;
        int ImageHeight;
        int ImageChannels;
        int ImageDesiredChannels = 4;

        unsigned char *ImageData = stbi_load("C:/test.png",
                                             &ImageWidth,
                                             &ImageHeight,
                                             &ImageChannels, ImageDesiredChannels);

        assert(ImageData);

        int ImagePitch = ImageWidth * 4;

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC ImageTextureDesc = {};

        ImageTextureDesc.Width = ImageWidth;
        ImageTextureDesc.Height = ImageHeight;
        ImageTextureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        ImageTextureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        ImageTextureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM_SRGB;
        ImageTextureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        ImageTextureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        ImageTextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
        ImageTextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;

        D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA ImageSubresourceData = {};

        ImageSubresourceData.pSysMem = ImageData;
        ImageSubresourceData.SysMemPitch = ImagePitch;

        hr = m_device->CreateTexture2D(&ImageTextureDesc, &ImageSubresourceData, &m_texture);

        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        free(ImageData);

        D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC ShaderResourceDesc = {};
        ShaderResourceDesc.Format = ImageTextureDesc.Format;
        ShaderResourceDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
        ShaderResourceDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
        ShaderResourceDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

        hr = m_device->CreateShaderResourceView(m_texture, &ShaderResourceDesc, &m_shaderResourceView);

        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    }

    hr = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void **)&m_texture);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    hr = m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(m_texture, 0, &m_renderTarget);
    if (FAILED(hr))
        qFatal("Failed to create render target: 0x%x", hr);

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC ImageSamplerDesc = {};

    ImageSamplerDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    ImageSamplerDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    ImageSamplerDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    ImageSamplerDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_CLAMP;
    ImageSamplerDesc.MipLODBias = 0.0f;
    ImageSamplerDesc.MaxAnisotropy = 1;
    ImageSamplerDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    ImageSamplerDesc.BorderColor[0] = 1.0f;
    ImageSamplerDesc.BorderColor[1] = 1.0f;
    ImageSamplerDesc.BorderColor[2] = 1.0f;
    ImageSamplerDesc.BorderColor[3] = 1.0f;
    ImageSamplerDesc.MinLOD = -FLT_MAX;
    ImageSamplerDesc.MaxLOD = FLT_MAX;

    hr = m_device->CreateSamplerState(&ImageSamplerDesc, &m_imageSamplerState);

    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    qDebug("init end");
}

void SquircleRenderer::render()
{
    qDebug() << "RENDERING!\n";

    D3D11_VIEWPORT v;
    v.TopLeftX = 0;
    v.TopLeftY = 0;
    v.Width = m_viewportSize.width();
    v.Height = m_viewportSize.height();
    v.MinDepth = 0;
    v.MaxDepth = 1;

    float Color[4] = {1.0f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f};

    auto hr = m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void **)&m_texture);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    m_context->ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTarget, Color);

    m_context->RSSetViewports(1, &v);
    m_context->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTarget, 0);

    m_context->VSSetShader(m_vs, nullptr, 0);
    m_context->PSSetShader(m_ps, nullptr, 0);

    m_context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
    m_context->IASetInputLayout(m_inputLayout);

    m_context->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &m_shaderResourceView);
    m_context->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &m_imageSamplerState);

    UINT stride = 4 * sizeof(float);
    UINT offset = 0;
    UINT num_vertices = sizeof(VertexData) / stride;

    m_context->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexData, &stride, &offset);

    m_context->Draw(num_vertices, 0);
    m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);
}

#include "d3d11squircle.moc"
```

```
//main.cpp

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQuick/QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickWindow::setSceneGraphBackend(QSGRendererInterface::Direct3D11Rhi);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:///scenegraph/d3d11underqml/main.qml"));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import D3D11UnderQML 1.0

Item {

    width: 720
    height: 720

    D3D11Squircle {
        SequentialAnimation on t {
            NumberAnimation { to: 1; duration: 2500; easing.type: Easing.InQuad }
            NumberAnimation { to: 0; duration: 2500; easing.type: Easing.OutQuad }
            loops: Animation.Infinite
            running: true
        }
    }
}
```

```
//shaders.hlsl
struct VS_Input
{
        float2 position: POSITION;
        float2 uv: UV;
};

struct VS_Output
{
        float4 position: SV_POSITION;
        float2 uv: UV;
};

VS_Output vs_main(VS_Input input)
{
        VS_Output output;
        output.position = float4(input.position, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        output.uv = input.uv;
        return output;
};

Texture2D my_texture;
SamplerState my_sampler;

float4 ps_main(VS_Output input): SV_TARGET
{
        return my_texture.Sample(my_sampler, input.uv);
};
```

So, I don't know what the problem is, `render` calls every frame, but it doesn't show texture